# Project 'PrjName' is missing required library: 'E:/arul/Android/libs/android-viewbadger.jar' PrjName

Tags: java, android

I have imported the android project in Eclipse on Mac System,

I got Error as " Project 'PrjName' is missing required library: 'E:/workspace/Android/libs/android-viewbadger.jar'  PrjName "

before that the project created and worked on Windows OS System,

please give any idea to clear that error....

Comment: Tell me onething that `Android` is folder for a project. Not an subfolder of Android-SDK? And, check whether your project in `Eclipse` on your mac that libs folder having that missing `.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your project settings, I'd say the build path is referencing something on your E: drive that just does not exist on the mac at that location.

Comment: That is Ok, Are we need to download android-viewbadger.jar? or it contains in android-sdk?

Comment: I have no idea. But its on the windows machine, you could just copy it over.