# Project 'PrjName' is missing required library: 'libs/android-viewbadger.jar' PrjName

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Project ‘PrjName’ is missing required library: ‘E:/arul/Android/libs/android-viewbadger.jar’ PrjName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928623/project-prjname-is-missing-required-library-e-arul-android-libs-android-vie)

In Android project got error as Project `PrjName` is missing required library: `/libs/android-viewbadger.jar` `PrjName`

Do we need to download `android-viewbadger.jar`? or have that contained in `android-sdk`?

Comment: android-viewbadger.jar   need download

Comment: Don't open same question twice. Your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12928623/1050058) was posted only 23 minutes.

Comment: i haven't gave cleared question and didn't got good result so i posted the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the project page says,

```
Author: Jeff Gilfelt

The code in this project is licensed under the Apache Software License 2.0. 
Copyright (c) 2011 readyState Software Ltd.
```

I don't think it is in Android sdk. here is the [link](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)